# How to dynamically import/require JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I've been working on importing json data to my js file and every time I use string variable I got 'Can't find module' error. I have exact file in my path though.

```
var file = 'example.json'
const datas = require(`./${file}`) // this failed (Can't find module for path './example.json')
//const datas = require('./'+file) // this failed (Can't find module for path './example.json')
//const datas = require(''+'./'+file) // this failed (Can't find module for path './example.json')
//const datas = require('./example.json') <= this works fine.

...
```

I want to load different json file every time I execute js file.
Should I use another way, for instance using process.argv, instead of require?
I really appreciate if you could resolve my problem..

Thank you, for always.

Comment: Try using fs and the path function?

Comment: If the fourth way works, others should too... Are you sure that the error is originated from this part of code?